# Can ReactDOM render list of elements

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of elements (Same element) that needs to be rendered multiple times within a page. All the examples I have seen of ReactDOM.render show that it can only render a single element. Is there a way to render a list of elements?

Note: Element may appear all over the page. I cannot make a list class such as `<ElementList/>` that renders multiple elements.

Vanilla usage:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Element/>,
document.getElementById('Element'));
```

Is there a way to pass in a list of elements or something equivalent instead such as

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Element/>,
listOfElements);
```

I know I can write a wrapper function, and call document.getElementById() multiple times, but is there something built-in into react that can handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `forEach` function:

```
listOfElements.forEach(el => ReactDOM.render(<Element/>, el);
```

Comment: @maddox2 I didn't know we could do this. This is cool. Does this mean that React will have to now manage a number of virtual doms? One per element?

Comment: @KumarM yes, react creates component for each call of `ReactDOM.render`. Those components are isolated and each has its own virtual dom.

Comment: @maddox2 Thanks. I wonder if it has any performance implications. But maybe it's a different question in itself.